# Use Powershell to the value of the department attribute using get-aduser without header information

Tags: powershell, active-directory

When I run this line in Powershell, for example

```
get-aduser someUserName -properties department | select department
```

I get these results:
department
---------------- 
Information Technology

I would like to just get the following:
Information Technology

Comment: You could try adding `Format-Table -HideTableHeaders`

Comment: `Select-Object -ExpandProperty department` .... basicst Powershell knowledge!!  ;-)

Comment: Format-Table -hideTableHeaders looks promising.  Can I get this to end up as a string?  Maybe using out-string?

Comment: Format cmdets like `Format-Table` are only suitable when you like to output something to your console screen. If you like to do further steps you should never use format cmdlets.  ... and they should always be the last cmdlet in a pipeline.

Comment: Another method: `(Get-ADUser someUserName -Properties Department).Department`

Comment: -ExpandProperty looks good, thank you!  If you want write as an answer I will mark that as correct answer

Comment: You should always read the help for the cmdlets you're using. You should read it completely including the examples. Start with [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-5.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply grab the resulting object and query its property.

In your example:

```
(Get-ADUser -Identity someUserName -Properties Department).Department
```

Edit: I've always seen examples using:

```
| Select-Object -ExpandProperty propertyName
```

However, I've never been clear on the differences between one method or the other - would be interesting to know if there is any.

I lean towards the former when pulling out single properties and it's also shorter while not compromising in verbosity for a saved script.

Comment: That looks like it works as well as select-object -expandProperty department.  Thank you

Comment: Looks like the main difference I can find is that using `Object.Property` will return $null if the property doesn't exist whereas using `Select-Object` will return an error.